# Shell with vim-editing shortcuts

Tags: shell, vim

Is there any shell in which you can edit your commands with vim shortcuts? Ideally, you would be in insert mode so that it wouldn't make any difference with other shells, but you could also use escape to go to normal mode and use vim commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash can be told to enter vi mode via `set -o vi`. See the man page for more details.

Comment: could you please give an example of the command in use, also, please specify whether one should look at `man bash` or `man gnome-terminal`

Comment: sorry, I see now that `set` is a built in command. I thought you had to pass it to `bash`/`gnome-terminal` upon initialisation

Answer (score 3):

zsh can do that. Put this in your .zshrc to default to vim insert mode:

```
bindkey -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Readline library itself can do this: instead of using `set -o vi` in bash, add `set editing-mode vi` to `~/.inputrc`. Bash and some other programs use readline, so you will get vi-like editing in them. Zsh does not, but it has its own implementation of vi-like editing mode (see @weronika's answer).

Comment: Better yet, put "set editing-mode vi" in /etc/inputrc.  Other people on the box will send you thank-you cards and maybe even candy. :)

Comment: @William Pursell I won't. I am fine with emacs mode + some custom bindings in readline and hardly modified emacs mode with vim `<C-o>` emulation in zsh.