# Force bash to use .vimrc in vi mode

Tags: bash, vim

Bash can be [set to operate in vim mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402729/shell-with-vim-editing-shortcuts) . However, my `.vimrc` is no longer used. Specifically, my mapping of <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> no longer works. I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit to insert mode. How do I tell bash to use my `.vimrc` file?

Comment: Bash is not vim - why would it use your .vimrc?

Comment: @CarlNorum I assumed it would be able to use `.vimrc` since it can operate in vi mode

Comment: Bash's vi mode is not vi.  It's just a little bit like vi so you'll feel at home if that's your taste.

Comment: @CarlNorum is there a `.bashvimrc` file?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Maybe the bash documentation would have some more information for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for bash-'s vi mode (which is just that: a vi input mode for bash, and has nothing at all to do with vi or vim).

It *does* have to do with readline/inputrc as far as I know so you could see whether you can

- bind keys the bash way
- from ~/.inputrc

links:

- [bash vi editing mode](http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/20040326082602)
- [.inputrc to make bash command-line editing like ksh](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1990)
- [[Wikia:]Use vi shortcuts in terminal](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal)

The last link contains a somewhat more advanced example of a `.inputrc` for use with bash:

```
# Edit options before rerunning previous command, eg: ls a b c -> ls -al a b c
"\e-": "\C-p\C-a\M-f "

# Cycle thru completions.
"\e/": menu-complete

# glob patterns without executing, eg: 'rm *x'
"\ee": glob-expand-word

# Vim style history search
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward

"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char

# Two escapes clear command line.
"\e\e": "\C-a\C-k"
```

Answer (score 3):

@sehe definitely has the most direct answer. BUT if you'd rather not mess with the .inputrc, there are [at least two other options](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1446/rapidly-invoke-an-editor-to-write-a-long-complex-or-tricky-command)

- `v`, which takes whatever commands you've written so far, or nothing at all, into the editor defined in your .bash_profile (use this line: `EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim`). save and quit executes the command. EDIT: this is to be executed from normal mode, so you'll still have to press ESC to get there :(
- `fc`, which is the handy ['fix command' command](http://htks.kylemilnes.com/2012/07/bash-fc-fix-command-cheatsheet.html). more on that one in `man bash`. EDIT: This one you type in insert mode.

Comment: I always wondered why vim would open up whenever I pressed 'v'

Comment: great advice, but could you edit the question to make it more clear, for example it is not obvious that those are meant to be issued in command mode instead of insert mode

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer has pointers, the cut-to-the chase answer is as follows:

In your .inputrc file, put

set keymap vi-insert

"jj": "\e"

You need to force the re-read of your .inputrc file.  This can be done by closing your terminal and re-opening it.  For prolonged experimentation with .inputrc file, so you don't have to log out and then back in, put this in too:

"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file

Then you can use Control-x, control-r to reread the init file and not have to log out and back in.

Answer (score -2):

in your .bashrc:

```
set -o vi
```

vim mode for bash

Comment: Is this supposed to work? It does not work for me, and I always believed the `editor` flag was for editors to use under certain conditions (ie. `svn commit -m`)

Comment: sorry my mistake, it should be: set -o vi